# Make fixed navbar stop at footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make this element (navbar) stop at footer. I had too much trouble to code the jQuery so it would move when top meets it, but I can't make it stop when it reaches footer. I tried with plain Javascript and with different jQueries but only this code would work. Thanks!

```js
var scrolljsTop = $('#scrolljs').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll >= scrolljsTop) {
    $('#scrolljs').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0'
    });
  } else {
    $('#scrolljs').css({
      position: 'relative'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1560px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: #006fc5;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4eb1ff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
#footer {
  height:500px;
  background-color:#2f3a5f
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul id="scrolljs">
    <li class="active" id="social-float">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: why is it 1560px in height?

Comment: I need the cssmenu that long in my webpage

Answer (score 1):

You need footer offset and on current scroll you need to add windowinnerHeight. I hope this will help you clearly. If you have any question ask me in comment.  :) . [FiddleLiveDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/sqs149uf/4/)

```js
   
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollHeight= ($('#scrolljs').offset().top + $('#scrolljs').height());
var currentScroll = ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
var footerOffset = $('#footer').offset().top;

 if (scrollHeight >= footerOffset){
    $('#scrolljs').css('position', 'absolute');
   }
  else if (currentScroll < footerOffset){
    $('#scrolljs').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
 }
});
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1560px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: #006fc5;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4eb1ff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
#footer {
  height:500px;
  background-color:#2f3a5f
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul id="scrolljs">
    <li class="active" id="social-float">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery change your `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` so it looks like this:

```
var scrolljsTop = $('#scrolljs').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll >= scrolljsTop) {
    $('#scrolljs').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0'
    });
  } else {
    $('#scrolljs').css({
      position: 'relative'
    });
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/kawnah/pen/EZaeYg

Please note, that since your menu is so big, it will stop pretty much right as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `cssmenu` into a div with id `content`

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id="cssmenu">
  <ul id="scrolljs">
    <li class="active" id="social-float">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

In your JQuery

Get the difference between height of `content` div and `csmenu` div

```
//Get the differnce of the two divs height here
var def_height =  $('#content').height() - $('#scrolljs').height();
```

Now, inside the scroll event listener in jQuery set the top to the maximum of the `def_height` calculated above.

```
/*
  Set max top scroll to the def_height
*/
var scroll = (currentScroll<def_height)?currentScroll:def_height;

$('#scrolljs').css('top',scroll + 'px');
```

Here is the full updated jQuery

```
var scrolljsTop = $('#scrolljs').offset().top;

//Get the differnce of the two divs height here
var def_height =  $('#content').height() - $('#scrolljs').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (currentScroll >= scrolljsTop) {
    /*
       Set max top scroll to the def_height
    */
    var scroll = (currentScroll<def_height)?currentScroll:def_height;

    $('#scrolljs').css('top',scroll + 'px');
  } else {
     $('#scrolljs').css('top','0');
  }
});
```

Here is the updated Snippet

```js
var scrolljsTop = $('#scrolljs').offset().top;

//Get the differnce of the two divs height here
var def_height =  $('#content').height() - $('#scrolljs').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll >= scrolljsTop) {
    /*
       Set max top scroll to the def_height
    */
    var scroll = (currentScroll<def_height)?currentScroll:def_height;
    
    $('#scrolljs').css('top',scroll + 'px');
  } else {
     $('#scrolljs').css('top','0');
  }
});
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1560px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 3px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: #006fc5;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4eb1ff;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
#footer {
  height:500px;
  background-color:#2f3a5f
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul id="scrolljs">
    <li class="active" id="social-float">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I am learning these stuff so I may ask a lot xD. How can I get the difference between the two divs and what is def_height?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment in the code, def_height stores the difference between two heights.

Comment: To find the difference between two divs, I fetch the height of the two divs using the jQuery `$('your_div_selector').height()` and finally just subtracted both heights

Comment: And using this in your scroll listener make sure the top margin of the scrolljs div is not more than that `diff_height` and hence it will stay inside the container.

Comment: I have a problem with scrolling in my webpage. Appearently, the jQuery takes the distance between the start (top) of the page and the cssmenu, and when top meets cssmenu the cssmenu goes that distance down. I can't figure it out.